# Azure AD Conditional Access only from Logic App Connector

Tags: azure-active-directory, conditional-statements, azure-logic-apps

We are trying to configure an AD account to only be used from an Outlook connector of a Logic App. We are interested that this account cannot be used in any other way; for example, it cannot be used to log in from a machine or access other services. We have been trying to do it with Conditional Access but couldn't find the correct settings. Maybe someone has been able to configure this or has some other way to do it?

I really appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Using Conditional Access it is not possible to Configure an AD account that can used only for outlook connector for a logic app and restrict like login to machine or other services. we are not sure about other ways to achieve it but through CA policies it is not possible.